# Detect if email was opened besides <img/> beacon strategy?

Tags: php, html, email

Is there another way to detect if a HTML email was opened by the target besides that strategy of adding a `<img src="site.com/someScript.php?var=email"/>` in the body of the message? I'm for some hours looking for this at the internet but all sites I found was about using this strategy which is almost certain that is gonna be blocked by a good portion of users (outlook for example).

I mean, there must be a guaranteed way, if mailChimp does it, I wanna do it too! Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  The whole point of blocking `<img>` is to prevent that.

Comment: Why would someone block that? Is there some security threat at it or something?

Comment: It's a privacy concern.

Comment: So how does services like MailChimp do it?

Comment: Using images.  (and link clicks as well)

Comment: Ok, so they block <img> from some but not from services associated with MailChimp?

Comment: No; they block all `<img>`s.  For privacy reasons, you can't do this reliably.  Period.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, how do they manage to send the <img> if the <img> is blocked?

Comment: The <img> tag is sent but the mail client allows the reader to refuse the content.